# How to install GEF/Draw2d source/javadoc for Eclipse PDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

After installing the Eclipse PDE from the [Eclipse downloads site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/node/1086), GEF and Draw2d don't seem to have working javadoc and source code attachments out of the box (The JFace source attachment is working fine).

In PDE projects under the "Plugin Dependencies" tree I see that all PDE JARs have attached source set to the same JARs. Yet, the JARs do not contain any sources - only class files. I tried instead point to this source attachment to a GEF source code JAR which I downloaded, but my change was automatically reverted back to the broken source attachment after rebooting the workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `Graphical Modeling Framework GEF SDK` using Help / Install New Software, it is in the `Modeling` section. The `SDK` versions include the source plugins.